# Transfer files which contains only digits and not letters using WinSCP in C#?

Tags: c#, winscp, winscp-net

I tried below with no success -

```
string mask = "Report01|*[A-Z]" +"*.txt"; //This line fails to select files which contains only digits
TransferOperationResult transferResult;
transferResult = session.getFiles("RemoteServerPath" +mask,"DestinationServerPath",false,transferOptions);
```

I'm trying to exclude all reports which contains letters after digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using WinSCP file [mask syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask).

But you can easily:

- iterate all files in the directory (using [`Session.ListDirectory`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory) or [`Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_enumerateremotefiles))
- do you custom selection logic (e.g. using [`Regex.Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match));
- and transfer the selected files one by one.

Something like this:

```
var files = session.ListDirectory("/remote/path").Files;
files = files.Where(_ => Regex.Match(_.Name, "^[0-9]+\.txt$"));
foreach (var file in files)
{
    session.GetFileToDirectory(file.FullName, @"C:\local\path");
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks Martin.